# JFace Data Binding: Update model only if all validators succeed

Tags: java, validation, data-binding, swt, jface

I'm using the JFace Data Binding. I have a Java bean with four different properties and all of them are bound to corresponding widgets with the update policy of `POLICY_CONVERT` so the model is updated only when I hit the Save button. The Save button's listener calls `DataBindingContext.updateTargets()` so the changes are displayed somewhere else.

Some of the properties have validators. Right now the app works in the way that when I hit the Save button, the invalid properties are not updated to the model and the valid ones are updated. But what I want to do is to **update the model if and only if all of the validors succeed**.

Is there a simple way of doing this with JFace? I can imagine doing it the hard way by creating a validator which validates all the properties but I hope there's some generic solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a Composite or Chained validator and put all your validators into it. Then if at least one validaotr fails to validate, your chained validator returns false.

For example:

```
if (validators != null && validators.length > 0) {
UpdateValueStrategy  update = new UpdateValueStrategy();
CompositeValidator validator = new CompositeValidator();
for (IValidator val2Add : validators) {
    validator.addValidator(val2Add);
}
update.setAfterConvertValidator(validator);
}

public class CompositeValidator implements IValidator {

private List<IValidator> validators = new ArrayList<IValidator>();
public IStatus validate(Object value) {
for (IValidator validator : validators) {
    IStatus status = validator.validate(value);
    if (IStatus.ERROR == status.getSeverity()) {
        return status;
    }
}
}
}
```

Then bind all controls with the same composite validator, but add control-specific validator as well.

You can also pass control to a validator and in case of an error you may want to show error control decoration for this field, if necessary.